# Map is not being updated after put statement

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Ok so as the title says i do not really see why my map is not being updated.

I have a "hotel" which has rooms. Each room can have a customer. Hotel rooms are populated at the very begining, and giving them Key (1-10) and Customer (which initially is null)

```
public class Hotel {

public Map<Integer, Room> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Hotel().run();
}
public void run() {
    // create rooms
    createRooms();
    // add customer 
    addCustmer(2, "Plastman");

    showRooms();

}
public void showRooms() {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Room> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer roomNumber = entry.getKey();
        Room room = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Room: " + roomNumber + " Customer " + room.getCutomer() );
    }
}
public void addCustmer(Integer roomNumber, String customer) {
    // check if room is empty.
    Room room = map.get(roomNumber);
    if(room.getCutomer() == null || room.getCutomer().equals("")) {
        // room is vacant.
        System.out.println("Room is vacant. Adding customer: " + customer);
        map.put(roomNumber, new Room(customer));
    } else {
        // room is NOT vacant.
        System.out.println("Room is NOT vacant");
    }
}
private void createRooms() {          
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i ++) {
        map.put(i,new Room(""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a minimum compiling example that reproduces the problem. Also, does the room is vacant printline actually fire?

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes it does show up in console. I will update my question accordingly

Comment: @merlin2011 code updated

Comment: Without the definition of the room class, this code will not compile.

Comment: Please re-add the code for the Room class as I feel the issue could be there.

Comment: Proper indentation would be helpful to make the code more readable.

Comment: Kieran Lavelle's solution below solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your room method you need to make the argument lowercase. That may be the issue.

```
public Room(String customer) {
    setCustomer(customer);        
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. With incorrect casing, the constructor just sets to local variable to itself.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right :). I had a typo in my Room class. i had a Uppercase customer in constructor instead of lower case :)

Comment: They get the best of us sometimes, enjoy.